# multiple swap in same page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i have on div which have left swipe

```
  $(".iframe-content").swipeleft(function(e) {

        alert ("test 1");
    });

    <div class="iframe-content">
<div class="noswipe">no swipe</div>
<div class="noswipe">no swipe</div>
<div class="noswipe">no swipe</div>
<div class="noswipe">no swipe</div>
    <div id="another-swipe">swipe here</div>
<div class="noswipe">no swipe</div>
<div class="noswipe">no swipe</div><div class="noswipe">no swipe</div>
    </div>
```

now my problem exactly is :

swipe on **iframe-content** is working fine but i have given another swipe on `another-swipe`

```
$(".another-swipe").swipeleft(function(e) {


        alert("test2")

    });
```

but its giving the previous alert not `alert("test2");` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use class instead of ID with another-swipe.
2. you can use e.stopPropagation(); to stop the upper call

See fiddle here (with click instead of swipe) : **http://jsfiddle.net/26w2q/**

HTML

```
<div class="iframe-content">
    <div class="noswipe">no swipe</div>
    <div class="noswipe">no swipe</div>
    <div class="noswipe">no swipe</div>
    <div class="noswipe">no swipe</div>
    <div class="another-swipe">swipe here</div> <<< USE class instead of id
    <div class="noswipe">no swipe</div>
    <div class="noswipe">no swipe</div>
    <div class="noswipe">no swipe</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".another-swipe").swipeleft(function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
alert("test2")
});
$(".iframe-content").swipeleft(function(e) {
    alert ("test 1");
});
```